# How can I use my own copy paste menu at device level in android?

Tags: android

I want to override system's default menu for copy paste so that everywhere only my  menu is used by user. Like some apps override lock screen or calling.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: I have got an Idea only.. I know it can be achieved using clipboard manager but the scope is only in the app we implement it. @Amy

Comment: for that you have to make system app.

Comment: Ok.. but how ??  Do I have to extends some system class or what?